# Why don't ORMs automatically set inverse associations in memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, orm, datamapper

Consider the following contrived example:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

c, p = Company.new, Project.new

c.projects << p
p.company  => c
```

As a project is added to the collection the inverse association to company is automatically set by Rails. Unfortunately, this is the only time Rails is smart enough to do this. Assignment from the other side does not add the object to the inverse collection.

```
c, p = Company.new, Project.new

p.company = c
c.projects => []
```

Many to many relationships don't do any automatic inverse reference assignment either. Both ActiveRecord and DataMapper exhibit this behavior. Is there a technical reason for this? Consistent associations before a save and reload happens would greatly speed up certain test cases and would make things cleaner in general.

Comment: You probably shouldn't get into the habit of initializing multiple objects on one line, as you've done here with `c` and `p`. This ends up creating difficult to maintain code.

Comment: @tadman can you justify that statement?

Comment: What happens if you later add arguments to the `new` calls? Then you end up with a mess. It's best to initialize one object per line. The `,` notation is normally reserved for swapping (`a,b = b,a`) or unpacking return values (`a,b = foo(...)`). It also means you need to read and match `c` and `Company.new`, `p` and `Project.new` which puts a lot of contextual overhead on what should not be tricky at all. How would this work with three, four or five initializations? Ugly, indeed. Anything that leads to confusion or is prone to error is risky at best.

Comment: Why not just break them out into single assignments when you feel that it has become too much to easily understand? Also, it sounds like the real culprit is that you need to pass so many attributes to your methods. I looked through my two recent gems, and only found two places [1](https://github.com/JoshCheek/surrogate/blob/2064828dfd8b19adb104bb1df812aa9b7bd728e9/lib/surrogate/method_definition.rb#L9-11) [2](https://github.com/JoshCheek/surrogate/blob/master/lib/surrogate/rspec/abstract_failure_message.rb#L22-27) where I needed to assign more than 2 values. I chose what made sense in context.

Answer (score 0):

You're mistaking what these two operations do, though it is a subtle effect that may not be communicated very clearly in the documentation.

The `<<` operator not only assigns `company_id` for your project, but it also saves it if the record exists. It also adds this to the `projects` cache for the company model.

The `company=` method only assigns and does not communicate between objects. An un-saved record cannot be loaded as you intend. Neither of these records are actually in the database, so `c.projects` will be an empty array unless you've explicitly added something to it, as you do in the first case.

Generally un-saved objects do not behave as well as their database persisted counterparts.

Comment: I don't see a reason for un-saved objects to behave differently compared to their persisted counterparts as far as caching associations go. Both the << and assoc= operators can cache the reference on both sides of the association. I can't think of any major technical challenges disallowing this behavior.

Comment: Theoretically, sure, but in practice it can be tricky to implement. If you're feeling ambitious, you could try to add this behavior as a patch and submit it to [the Rails GitHub project](https://github.com/rails/rails) or publish it as a stand-alone gem.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9522. Automatic inverse associations might become a feature in future versions of Rails.